# TI Inspire CX CAS unable to do integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, calculator

Here is the math problem I am trying to do:
[image]

So I want to take the integral of v(t) to get s(t) then solve for c. I typed in v(t) in my ti inspire cas, assuming it would simplify it down. However it doesn't:
[image]

Usually, the calculator simplifies integrals, but this time it didn't. What am I doing wrong on the calculator?

Thanks!

-- Update --

If I ask the calculator to solve for the definite integral it does that correctly:
[image]

So again, how do I get it to just do the indefinite integral?

Comment: Why do you need the antiderivative?

Comment: At first, I was just planning on solving for the actual function of s(t). In the update, I posted, I solved it by simply taking the definite integral from 7 to 2. But I'm now just curious, if I had wanted to take the antiderivative, how would I on the calculator

Comment: It soes not surprise me that the calculator cannot do it as the result is $$\frac{i \left(-2 i t \left(\text{Li}_2\left(\left(5-2 \sqrt{6}\right) e^{2 i t}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\left(2 \sqrt{6}+5\right) e^{2 i t}\right)\right)-\text{Li}_3\left(\left(2 \sqrt{6}+5\right) e^{2 i t}\right)+\text{Li}_3\left(\left(5-2 \sqrt{6}\right) e^{2 i t}\right)+2 t^2 \left(\log \left(1+\left(2 \sqrt{6}-5\right) e^{2 i t}\right)-\log \left(1-\left(2 \sqrt{6}+5\right) e^{2 i t}\right)\right)\right)}{4 \sqrt{6}}$$ It uses numerical methods for the definite variant.